# Dual slider control with custom skin

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, slider

I'm currently trying to create a page for users to select two points from a range, using a slide control. The first point in the range is when an alert will be sent to the user, the second point is a max limit. What I would like to do is have the bar colored green from the 0 point to the first slider point, then orange between the two sliders, and lastly red from the second slider up to the other end of the bar.

Does anyone know of an easy was I can do this or of a slider control that can be skinned to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didnt manage to find a slider that did exactly what I was after. I ended up going with the JQuery UI slider as seen [here](http://jqueryui.com/home). It's a very nice slider although it has its issues it was the simplest one I could find that was still a close match to my original specifications.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Slider) seems to be what you want. See the Mootools documentation for details.